# LIBGDX Cannot resolve dependecy

Tags: java, libgdx

Im trying to add `compile 'com.droidninja:filepicker:2.0.8'` in build.gradle android dependency block, results in a gradle error

> Failed to resolve: `com.droidninja:filepicker:2.0.8`

I created a android project with a empty activity, and added the dependency and gave me this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

I searched the error and put this block in build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This fixed the error in the android project, so I came back to my libgdx project and added the above block, but still

> Failed to resolve: `com.droidninja:filepicker:2.0.8`

How can I add this dependency in my libgdx project?

Comment: show your `build.gradle` file ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan  currently surviving hurricane Maria at Puerto Rico, no electricity here...  but the only thing I added was the dependency, in the android section

Comment: have you added `jcenter()` in repository list

Comment: @AbhishekAryan yes it was there already

Comment: I tested your artifact by adding `compile "com.droidninja:filepicker:2.0.8"`, gradle not showing me any error.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan  Thats weird... as soon as I can I post my build.gradle .... but I am sure that jcenter() was there, thats  the first thing I checked